# Multiple questions with three close votes are still open or three delete votes aren't deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I opened a question that already had 3 close votes but was nevertheless active.  I refreshed my browser couple of times but it had no effect. I was even allowed to submit another close request. And still it remained open.

I saw similar bug report questions, but I did not find any with a clear answer. For example: [Question had enough close votes to be closed, but was not closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359550/question-had-enough-close-votes-to-be-closed-but-was-not-closed)

The question is now deleted but seems that it's so only because the author deleted it.

##### Examples [*Please don't go and vote on any of these (i.e., please avoid applying the meta effect).* Having examples is beneficial for the developers in order to identify and fix the problem, but the questions/users shouldn't be negatively (or positively) impacted because of a system error.]

###### 3 close-votes, but not closed

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78035076/how-to-be-the-best-specific-way-in-a-wordpress-theme (deleted by author; 10K+ needed to see)
- [WebScrap project issue with selenium [NoSuchElementException] div finding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78030236/webscrap-project-issue-with-selenium-nosuchelementexception-div-finding-issues)

##### Even when the issue which caused this is resolved, the affected questions and answers will still need to have their status changed (i.e., be closed or deleted, as voted).

Comment: It is happening to many questions. I just reviewed a question in the CV Queue and got an error message, refreshed the page and it shows I can't review the item anymore, yet my review was not counted, but if I go to the question, it is showing my vote as the 3rd close vote.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78030236/webscrap-project-issue-with-selenium-nosuchelementexception-div-finding-issues someone has seriously broken something.

Comment: Seems like stackexchange is experiencing some network issues, I'm unable to edit/delete any posts and I get a silence timeout with the maintenance response, even tho there is no maintenance mentioned, nor does stackstatus show anything.

Comment: [3 delete votes on an undeleted question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsaGA.png)

Comment: @VLAZ - also nice...

Comment: Finally the [Stack Exchange Network Health Page](https://p.us3.datadoghq.com/sb/bc887ca0-08ce-11ed-a269-da7ad0900003-33d1e48ca7d76da0b86577abb0d28c1d?refresh_mode=sliding&theme=dark&from_ts=1708444502617&to_ts=1708530902617&live=true) is showing some errors. I'm once again able to delete my own posts, so seems like they fixed something. Questions with already 3 votes probably need to be cleaned tho.

Comment: @0stone0 FYI: The maintenance page is the default fallback for when the request takes longer then 5 seconds to generate a response.

Comment: @VLAZ well, at least they didn't use the `dsa` tag.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure if this is what you're alluding to, or just a coincidence but they did. In the screenshot you can see I've edited the post and that was my edit.

Comment: @VLAZ my sadness knows no bounds. Just when I regain some faith in humanity, it is dashed. Perhaps it is time to let AI overtake and destroy us. Perhaps the machines will do better.

Comment: Our devs were looking into this and were not able to reproduce. Is this still an issue?

Comment: @Bella_Blue it was on the day it was reported. At the same time there were severe slowdowns when doing actions, that most likely either caused the voting problems. Or were also a symptom of the same underlying issue. It seems some actions did not fully complete, like three close votes or three delete votes that did not close or delete a post. See also a bounty that claims it's awarded bu no rep did go to the poster and the timeline has no record of it ending: [Why is the Half Bounty awarded on Post Answer but not showing in Reputation Score?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429262)

Comment: I've updated the status as non-repro, we were not able to replicate it on our end.

Comment: @tanj92 as mentioned by VLAZ the issue that caused this was temporary and resolved on the same day. The expectation from staff for this question would be to find any similar actions that are left in an incomplete state and complete them. So I'd normally expect a status completed tag once that is done.