# Why is the Half Bounty awarded on Post Answer but not showing in Reputation Score?

Tags: support, bug, status-review, reputation, bounty

This just seems like strange behavior on SO. Can someone explain?

If an answer gets awarded the half bounty (automatically) when the OP neglects to award the bounty after the grace period ends, shouldn't the bounty awarded show up in the profile (reputation score) of the user whose answer got the most upvotes?

Here is the post:
[Inconsistent behavior between browsers with deeply nested subgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77619938/inconsistent-behavior-between-browsers-with-deeply-nested-subgrid/77990099#77990099)

It has been several days after the grace period ended, and it looks like the half bounty was issued (in the post), but I can confirm it hasn't been awarded or hasn't updated in the user's profile stats that provided the answer with the most upvotes.

Is this a bug? Definitely not a caching problem.

Comment: Looks indeed like a bug, there isn't even a "notice removed" entry in the question timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77619938/timeline

Comment: For comparison: This is how the timeline of a question where the bounty expired without manual awarding looks usually: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62608763/timeline

Comment: Potentially related: [Multiple questions with three close votes are still open or three delete votes aren't deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428206/multiple-questions-with-three-close-votes-are-still-open-or-three-delete-votes-a) From the timeline the bounty should have been automatically awarded on 21st Feb, the site had some issues for a brief period of time that day which caused the issue mentioned in the linked question.

Comment: Looks like the bounty is in some parallel universe or perhaps got stuck on the 7 1/2 floor?

Comment: @jottin It's off to Pitcairn.