# Questions with three close/delete votes are STILL not closed or deleted

Tags: bug, status-review, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I saw this question: [Multiple questions with three close votes are still open or three delete votes aren't deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428206/16217248)

I also saw that the question was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so the staff apparently believe they have fixed the issue. A moderator told me that if I am still able to reproduce a problem that has already been marked as fixed, I should just create a separate Meta thread.

However, I am still now able to reproduce the described problem on the following questions after the ostensible fix:

- [Duplicating dialog box on the same html page won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78166672/16217248) (I voted on 3/17/24 23:27:10 UTC)
- [MYSQL Subtracting values between rows where the subtracted number is displayed along with the rows from which it is subtracted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78177006/16217248) (I voted on 3/17/24 23:28:18 UTC)

They have 3 close votes and are not closed. When I hover the close votes, a message says '0 more votes are needed to close the question.' This happened when I voted to close the question, and clicked vote to close, and the dialog did not disappear for a while, so I refreshed the page and saw 3 close votes, but the question was not closed.

I believe this may be a time-specific issue, as I have not been able to reproduce the issue until I suddenly did so twice in a row.

Comment: Both of those questions has been closed finally, but has required **4 votes** for close: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78166672/timeline#history_d48be83e-b765-4aec-b465-bbd3dd98e9a8, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78177006/timeline#history_6db54342-2e1c-43e6-8784-75d86bdf219f

Comment: @Tsyvarev A very unique situation. Before this bug, only moderators voting to close questions with 3 votes **before** the change of requiring 5 votes to 3 could result in 4 close voters for a question.